# Need some pointer on the approach for proxying the request based on complete request URL in Nginx for 1000 of APIs

Tags: nginx

I have 2 applications(One Being Simulator and the other one is real application) running with the same root context and trying to use Nginx as a proxy to these 2 applications. I have around 1000 APIs being served from Simulator while the others should go to the Real application server.

Could someone please let me know a good approach for writing this routing logic for Simulator APIs as how to configure those 1000 APIs as i do not have any regex pattern to identify those APIs?

Comment: You can try to get required application from the request URI using [`map`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_map_module.html) block, something like `map $uri $app { ... }`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Thank you @IvanShatsky, it helped